# Determining the largest prime such that a group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{50}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question specifically asks " Determine the largest prime number $p$ such that $(U(p^2), * \mod p)$ is isomorphic a subgroup of $s_{50}$.

So far I have the order of any multiplicative group $\mod p^2$ is $(p^2-p)$ so I need to find the largest order of the disjoint cycles of $S_{50}$ that equal $(p^2-p)$.

Is this wrong? I am not entirely sure how to do this problem or proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   Note that $p^2-p=p(p-1)$. You could have disjoint cycles of lengths $22$ and $23$

Answer (score 0):

$U(p^2)$ is cyclic of order $p(p-1)$. So the question is: when does $S_{50}$ contain an element of that order?

The primes less than $50$ are $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47$.

For $p=37$ we have $p-1=36=4\cdot 9$. Since $37+4+9=50$, $p=37$ works.

On the other hand, $p>37$ does not work:

$p=41$: we have $p-1=40=8 \cdot 5$ and $41+8+5 > 50$.

$p=43$: we have $p-1=42=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$ and $43+2+3+7 > 50$.

$p=47$: we have $p-1=46=2 \cdot 23$ and $47+2+23 > 50$.

(There are other cases, such as $p-1=2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5$ for $p=41$, but they don't work either.)